# Logic when checking availability of slot bookings in SQL

Tags: php, sql

I have simple testing system that has fixed time slots linked to a laptop for training days called `event_machine_time`

```
*************************************************
id   * machine_laptop * machine_name * start_time
*************************************************
1    * Lenovo 001     * XXX45435     * 09:00
2    * Lenovo 001     * XXX45435     * 11:00
3    * Lenovo 002     * YER45435     * 09:00
4    * Lenovo 002     * YER45435     * 11:00
*************************************************
```

I have another table that collects information about the booking details called `event_booking`

```
**************************************************************
id * information_id *   machine_time_id * firstname * surname
**************************************************************
1  * 1              *  1                * Joe       * Blogs
2  * 1              *  3                * Jane      * Smith
**************************************************************
```

The table above tie into another table `event_information` that holds the event information

```
*****************************************
id * date       *  name
*****************************************
1  * 08-21-2017 *  Testing Day
2  * 08-21-2017 *  Testing Day Follow-Up           
*****************************************
```

So based on the information above I know the following booking have been made:

```
Testing day on 21st August 2017
Joe Blogs - XXX45435 - 09:00
Jane Smith - YER45435 - 09:00
```

So I know I can check all bookings by joining the two tables

```
SELECT
event_machine_time.id AS machine_id,
event_booking.id AS booking_id,
event_machine_time.start_time,
event_machine_time.machine_laptop,
FROM event_machine_time
LEFT JOIN event_booking
ON event_machine_time.id=event_booking.machine_time_id
WHERE information_id= :id
ORDER BY machine_name ASC, start_time ASC
```

However I want to create a select box that just shows the available times. I can use JS to filter the machines but I want to show all the times but disable any slots that are already booked. This is where I get stuck.

It's super simple to output the slots:

```
...choose the machine via a select box and call the Ajax request...

$machine_id = $_POST['machine'];

$Get_Testing_Slots_Query = "
SELECT *
    FROM event_booking
    WHERE machine_time_id = :t_id";

$Get_Testing_Slots = $dbconn->prepare($Get_Testing_Slots_Query);
    $Get_Testing_Slots->bindParam(":t_id",$machine_id);
    $Get_Testing_Slots->execute();

...output all the testing slots...
```

I know I could just load all the slots using `foreach` then run a `function` that checks if the slots free, but this seems like a really convoluted way to do it.

Is there a way I can output all the `start_times` and sort of link it back to `machine_time_id` so I know there is a booking?

So essentially I would like the select box to show the following:

```
************
* XXX45435 * (selected above)
************

***************
*9:00am BOOKED*
*11:00am FREE *
***************
```

EDIT:

Apologies I missed a crucial part! An additional table which holds the event information called `event_information`. I have made the changes above.

Comment: Doesn't your query with the LEFT JOIN already do what you are trying to do? if `booking_id` is null then the slot is open, otherwise It's booked.

Comment: So unless I'm doing it wrong `LEFT JOIN` outputs anything with a match, it doesn't output null. So it shows `event_machine_time` `id` 1 & 3 but not 2 & 4

Comment: @JosephGregory A `LEFT JOIN` is a left outer join, which means that it will return all of the rows from the "table on the left" (in this case event_machine_time), and attempt to find matching rows from the table on the right. If there isn't a matching row, it will return the specified columns from the left table, and return null for the columns from the right table. What you're describing is an inner join.

Comment: Try this `SELECT *
FROM  event_information A
inner join event_machine_time B on (1=1)
left join event_booking C on (B.id = C.machine_time_id and A.id = C.information_id )
WHERE A.id = '1'`

Comment: Its a cartesian product between `event_machine_time` and `event_information` because every computer is available at all slots for each event. Then it checks to see if the machine is booked at that time, date, and slot.

Comment: @bassxzero thats exactly what I needed!! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM event_information A
inner join event_machine_time B on (1=1) 
left join event_booking C on (B.id = C.machine_time_id and A.id = C.information_id ) 
WHERE A.id = '1'
```

It's a cartesian product between event_machine_time and event_information because every computer is available at all slots for each event. Then it checks to see if the machine is booked at that time, date, and slot.

Answer (score 0):

You're already using a left join in your query, and selecting a column from `event_booking`, so you're almost there!

The SQL statement will return a null value for `booking_id` if there is nothing booked for that particular time slot in `event_machine_time`. Try add something like this to your loop that is outputting each line in your select box:

```
print $row['start_time'];

if (is_null($row['booking_id']))
{
    print ' FREE';
}
else
{
    print ' BOOKED';
}
```

Comment: Should you be testing `$row['booking_id'] === null` or `is_null($row['booking_id'])` instead of comparing it to the empty string?

Comment: @bassxzero You're right, it should be checking for a null value, not a blank value.

Comment: Apologies I missed a linking table which I have now rectified!

Comment: @JosephGregory Does the new table alter how this logic should work? Your question still shows that you want the same output in your select box. I also saw that your comment to your question indicated that there may be some confusion about a left join and an inner join.